# Magento change forward slash in product url key to dash automatically

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Magento change forward slash(/) in product url key to dash(-) automatically like below which i don't want:-

category/subcategory/productname to category-subcategory-productname

Answer (score 1):

everything what you have to do is to change in the file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Category.php in the method  getCategoryUrlPath

from:

```
if ($slash) {
    $regexp     = '#('.preg_quote($this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($storeId), '#').')/$#i';
    $replace    = '/';
}
```

to:

```
if ($slash) {
    $regexp     = '#('.preg_quote($this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($storeId), '#').')/$#i';
    $replace    = '-';
}
```

and in the file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php in the method getProductRequestPath

from:

```
$requestPath = $categoryUrl . '/' . $urlKey;
```

to:

```
$requestPath = $categoryUrl . '-' . $urlKey;
```

after that do the re-indexing (Catalog URL Rewrites) and clean the cache and that's it.

**UPDATE:**

regarding the Feroz's comments:

in order to have everywhere "/" even in product url as well, first you should reverse all above changes which are in those post and then in the class `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Url.php` instead of:

```
public function formatUrlKey($str)
{
    $urlKey = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', Mage::helper('catalog/product_url')->format($str));
    $urlKey = strtolower($urlKey);
    $urlKey = trim($urlKey, '-');

    return $urlKey;
}
```

set:

```
public function formatUrlKey($str)
{
    $urlKey = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '/', Mage::helper('catalog/product_url')->format($str));
    $urlKey = strtolower($urlKey);
    $urlKey = trim($urlKey, '/');

    return $urlKey;
}
```

Comment: of course, you should override those classes in you local module, not directly to change in the core

Comment: marko, i tried the above changes and also did the reindexing, still it takes '-' instead of '/' in my product url key in admin when saving product information.

Comment: also when i echo and die in the function u told above in does not stop there.so, i think that function is not called when we save product information..i m using mage 1.7.0.2

Comment: @Feroz sorry, I think that I didn't understand you. Before it was with "/", but after changing the code, it should be with "-". And now, there is no more "/" in the urls

Comment: marko, before it was with '-' only.

I want slash to be save in my product url key as cat/prodname and not cat-prodname, slash get change to dash when i save product.

Comment: marko, in the file(Catalog\Model\Url.php) u said, there were no such function defination, i found in Catalog\Model\Category.php and Catalog\Model\Product\Url.php and change the way u said to replace - with / and did reindexing, caching but still no success.

Comment: ah sorry, i copied wrong one. This is the right one: `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Url.php`

Comment: marko, tried that file also, no success and also i add echo, die code in that function but the call does not go there.

Comment: maybe that class is already overridden in local or community pool? try to search in your magento for method formatUrlKey in order to find if it's overridden

Comment: marko, i checked, there is no such overridden for that function in local and community.

Comment: hm, which version of magento do you use? Maybe it's cache problem. Try to delete it.

Comment: i installed 1.7.0.2 and it works for me. After that changing, try to re-index, clean the cache again, and try to edit one product, remove 'URL Key', I mean set it a blank, and then save product.

Comment: hi marko, i can also save blank url key, i want to save url key in this pattern 'category/productname' which on save change automatically to 'category-productname'..can u plz chk this in ur install version..

Comment: when I enter blank url key, it automatically saves as "category/productname". Did you do undo of my answer before update section? If not, do it please, maybe this is a problem

Comment: how to achieve the same in magento2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you were asking the opposite: with this extension: https://github.com/fullbl/snh_settings_CategoryParentUrl
you can remove parents path and use "/" in url-keys for categories!